# Problem during replacing word/phrases from a text file using a set in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file, replace

Suppose I am having a list (`new_list`) with 3000 sentences, where each sentences are separated by a comma mark (`,`).

Example (a part):

```
new_list = ['air purity controller, to detect pollution and letting cold air in', 'air quality in my home by air conditioning', 'air conditioner depending on home', 'household alarm clock for time']
```

I want to replace certain words (single word or phrase) from the `new_list` by adding some special characters (at the start and end). I am doing this by the help of a set.

Example of the set:

```
dict = {'air conditioner', 'air', 'air quality', 'house', 'air conditioning', 'alarm clock'}
```

The size of the set (dict) is 317. I want to scan each word of the `new_list` and replace when there is a match with the set by appending special characters at the starting and end position. Further if a match occur and the resulted word is a phrase from the set, then additionally it would add a special character (_) in between along with appending special character at the both starting and end points.

I have tried but failing. Please suggest where I am going wrong (i don't think so, I am wrong). The `new_list` and dict are shown above.

```
import re, csv, nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import regexp_tokenize

with open("raw_data.txt", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f1:
   reader = csv.reader(f1, skipinitialspace=True)
   new_list = next(reader)
   with open('updatd_file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f2:
      dic = {'air conditioner', 'air quality', 'air conditioning', 'air', 'house', 'alarm clock'}
      dic = {i : i.replace(' ', '_') for i in dic} 
      pattern = re.compile(r"\b("+"|".join(dic)+r")\b")
      modify_reqs = [pattern.sub(lambda x: "_{}_".format(dic[x.group()]), i) for i in new_list]
      sw = (stopwords.words('english'))
      unfiltered_tokens = [[word for word in regexp_tokenize(word, pattern=r"\s|[\d]|[^\wa-z+]", gaps=True) if word not in sw] for word in modify_reqs]
      f2.write(str(unfiltered_tokens))
```

I am executing this program and writing the results onto a file. When I check the output file, I can see the words in the desired order (missing few words) but sometimes i am unable to see this. How is this strange behavior, I am unable to understand and explore.

That is sometimes, I am able to find the phrase in the correct order (as expected) that is `'_air_conditioning_'` but next time when I execute this fragment, i find the same word as `'_air_'`, `'conditioning'` (separated). Same thing also happened with the other phrases like `air quality`, `air conditioning`, etc. The problem is with the phrases not with the single word. 
Please note that in the set (dict) I have 317 words and `new_list` containing almost 3000 sentences. Not possible to show all here.
How is this possible? I am trying this since 7-8 days its frustrating now.

Comment: First sort your dictionnary in descending length of word.

Comment: I did not get you @toto.

Comment: A `set` and a `dict` are not the same thing, and neither is guaranteed to be ordered.

Comment: Why do not you provide a toy example and the result you want to achieve? It would simplify the job to anyone is reading your question. yourself included.

Comment: Actually it is not possible for a file containing large size. I have cross-checked the same with a small list and everything works perfectly (as expected). I have mentioned this in the query itself

Comment: It is because you did not provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Therefore, trying to understand your problem becomes quite frustrating. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Toto! Sorted order (by descending order word length) is helpful in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @Toto really helped me to resolve the issue.

I have sorted the used `set` in the descending order of the length of words using the keyword `sorted`.

```
dic = sorted(dic, key=len, reverse=True)
```